# make imagebutton visible on click of hyperlink javascript vb.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, imagebutton

i am new to javascript and i really need some help starting up. here's a situation.
i have a set of hyperlinks which shows image on click. but i can't get it to work. Help!

```
  <td>
  <asp:HyperLink ID="hyplnkcat" Text='<%#Eval("CategoryNameEn") %>' onclick="return MakeVisible(imgselect);" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
  <asp:Label ID = "countcat" Text='' runat ="server">countcat</asp:Label>
  <asp:ImageButton ID="imgselect" runat ="server" Visible ="false" CommandArgument ='<%#Eval("CategoryNameEn") %>' ImageUrl="images/arrow_black.gif"/>
  </td>

   <td>
   <asp:Literal ID = "litcat" text='<%#Eval("CategoryCode") %>' Visible ="false" runat ="server" ></asp:Literal>
   </td>
.
.
.

      <script type="text/javascript">

           $("#hyplnkbrand").click(function MakeVisible(imgselect) {
           $("#imgselect").show("slow", function() {
                   // Animation complete.
               });
           });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the rendered version of your controls (i.e. use Firebug in Firefox to check your HTML) you will notice that the ID's of your .NET controls don't exist anymore (but the ID's look similar like 'ctl00_ctlxxx_hyplnkcat').

As Javascript is bind to the client side via the browser it's impossible to activate the jQuery as, for Javascript, your controls don't exist on that side anymore...

There are several options for this problem:

1.You can use class names instead of ID's to bind your jQuery code (you need to add each class to each .NET control and replace all the ID's into classes in jQuery):

```
<asp:HyperLink CssClass="hyplnkcat" ID="hyplnkcat" Text='<%#Eval("CategoryNameEn") %>' onclick="return MakeVisible(imgselect);" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>

$(".hyplnkbrand").click(function MakeVisible(...));
```

2.Depend on the .NET Framework you are using, you can use the '[ClientId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)' property to generate a fixed ID name for your elements instead of the .NET Frameworks version. This way, the ID's will be the way as they should be on the client side and you should be able to bind the jQuery actions.

Tip: DON'T use the generated ID by .NET to bind your jQuery actions as this is auto generated by .NET and might change whenever you change something in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the issue is because you have set the Visiblity property of the `ImageButton` to false.

`Visible ="false"`

This will stop it from being rendered to your browser.

What you need to do is set the `style` of the `ImageButton` to be `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` then you will be able to find your element using JS.

then you can do something like

```
$("#" + <% imgselect.ClientID %>).show("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```